# How to delete all entries except the last 10 in the table with Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I tried to use the destroy + offset + limit method, but nothing worked.

```
Model.destroy({ offset: 10, limit: 5000 })
```

Comment: LIMIT 10000000 OFFSET 10

Comment: `destroy` does not have `order` option so you can't guarantee the order of records that will be deleted. What is the difference between these 10 records and others?

Comment: They don't have a difference, but I can make a time difference, but I don't need a time difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`limit` and `offset` are not supported in the `Destroy` query, alternatively it can be done using the `findAll` query and then destroy all the results.

```
Model.findAll({ offset: 10, limit: 5000 })
  .then(records => {
     records.forEach(record => record.destry())
  })
```